# How to configure arrow key scroll step in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard, scrolling

I upgraded from Firefox 3.6 to Firefox 19 (!!! how do they manage to release *sixteen* major versions in just three years?), and now find that the arrow keys scroll the page by much more than they used to. Previously a single downarrow press would scroll down by about 1 line of text; now it scrolls 2 or 3 lines. That is rather annoying.

I suppose there must be some setting in about:config I can adjust to get the single-line scrolling back, but where? Searching for "scroll" in the list doesn't turn up anything promising (which works).

(I've seen various places on the web recommend the "Yet another smooth scrolling" extension, but it doesn't do quite the right thing -- it lets me control the amount of scroll alright, but even if I turn its smoothness controls all the way down to 0, it stills seems to scroll each line in two quick steps rather than immediately).

Comment: The can release 16 major version quite easily with their following.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work without any extensions.

First, you'll want to adjust the `toolkit.scrollbox.verticalScrollDistance` flag in `about:config`. This should be the scrolled distance. My current default value seems to be 3 (which would match your suspicion).

If you want to disable the smooth scrolling effect, you can adjust `general.smoothScroll.lines.durationMaxMS` and `general.smoothScroll.lines.durationMinMS` to 0.

Comment: That works, thanks! Don't know how I could have overlooked that setting.

Comment: The duration setting works only if another setting (use smooth scrolling) is turned on in "about:preferences".