# How to switch off Firefox Scrolling Delay

Tags: firefox, scrolling, delay

How can I disable the delay before soft scrolling starts, when scrolling with the arrow keys? This is very annoying.

Comment: Which OS and which Firefox version? Does it go away if you hit F7?

Comment: Does it happen on othe programs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with Firefox, and everything to do with your unspecified OS.

Comment: Here's one answer: https://superuser.com/questions/568339/how-to-configure-arrow-key-scroll-step-in-firefox  The duration setting works only if another setting (use smooth scrolling) is turned on in "about:preferences". If you turn off the "use smooth scrolling" setting, there will be no delay. There are also smooth scrolling extensions that can control this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that in **Windows** this delay is not specific to Firefox or any app, it's a system wide setting called **keyboard repeat delay**, to adjust it to your needs open the good ol' **Control Panel > Keyboard > Speed**. Use the slider under Repeat delay to shorten the time.

Refer to this [tutorial](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-keyboard-character-repeat-delay-in-windows-11.12420/) for much more detailed instructions.

**Tested in Windows 11 22H2**