# Remove initial pause when scrolling with arrow-keys - Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, scrolling

Windows gives an initial-pause when pressing a key that can be altered, but I would prefer to not do this since it will affect more than scrolling.

An extension for Chrome does this; called "Smooth Key scrolling" but I can't replicate this behaviour with any firefox-extension.

They have a website which outputs exactly what I want: https://www.smoothkeyscroll.com/ So I know this is possible without going into system-wide options. Can this be implemented to work with every website? Maybe in about:config? Or is there an extension doing this?

Comment: This lists some settings you could play with: https://github.com/yokoffing/Betterfox/blob/main/Smoothfox.js

Comment: Thanks. I have tested some of these. While I was able to change the behaviour of scrolling, I couldn't replicate the behaviour for scrolling using arrow-keys described above. I suppose I will have to wait for some saint to get annoyed with this minor pause and make an extension.

Comment: There is a solution for Windows, but it is not Firefox specific: https://superuser.com/questions/1805065/how-to-switch-off-firefox-scrolling-delay

Comment: I dont know about extensions, but if that really bothers you you could look into Autohotkey. It can emulate no-delay keystrokes. But even then I guess you would have to bind it to other key, like say Ctrl-up Ctrl-down or other, because Up and Down keys not only scroll but are also important for editing text and other functionality in firefox.